# How to integrate sms gateway in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, sms

I have a project of codeigniter. There are already sms gateways like clickatell and twilio. I want to include one more sms gateway named lifetimesms.com in my project. Here is the code for lifetimesms gateway.

```
<?php
  $username = 'username';
  $password = 'password';
  $to = '44xxxxxxxx';
  $from = 'Brand';
  $message = 'Test SMS from Lifetimesms.com';
  $url = "http://Lifetimesms.com/plain?username=".$username."&password=".$password."&to=".$to."&from=".urlencode($from)."&message=".urlencode($message)."";
//Curl Start
 $ch  =  curl_init();
 $timeout  =  30;
 curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url) ;
 curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout) ;
 $response = curl_exec($ch) ;
 curl_close($ch) ; 
 //Write out the response
 echo $response ;

 ?>
```

What should for this in codeigniter?

Comment: That should be it for CI

Comment: What problem are you actually having?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just add it directly to a controller file ( SMS.php )
like this

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


class SMS extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }



    public function index()
    {

  $username = 'username';
  $password = 'password';
  $to = '44xxxxxxxx';
  $from = 'Brand';
  $message = 'Test SMS from Lifetimesms.com';
  $url = "http://Lifetimesms.com/plain?username=".$username."&password=".$password."&to=".$to."&from=".urlencode($from)."&message=".urlencode($message)."";
//Curl Start
 $ch  =  curl_init();
 $timeout  =  30;
 curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url) ;
 curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout) ;
 $response = curl_exec($ch) ;
 curl_close($ch) ; 
 //Write out the response
 die($response);
}

}
```

then just run like this
http://xxxx.com/codeigniter/sms